# How to listen terminate signal from worker in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, node-worker-threads

I have a main process which spawn one new thread using `worker_threads`. Main process in some particular cases have to close this thread without mattering if it has finished its task or not, so MainThread makes use of [terminate()](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_terminate) to stop the thread. However, this thread spawn different dependencies that need to be closed before exiting. These dependencies have to be closed from the thread, so I cannot use `worker.on('exit')` since it is run on main process.

Is there some way of listening the terminate from the worker itself?

Some minimal example of what I would like to achieve.

```
const {Worker, isMainThread} = require('worker_threads');

if (isMainThread) {
  const worker = new Worker(__filename);
  worker.on('message', console.log);
  worker.on('error', console.log);
  worker.on('exit', console.log);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Worker is gonna be terminated');
    worker.terminate();
  }, 5000);
} else {
  (async () => {
    console.log('I am the worker');
    // This thread will spawn its own dependencies, so I want to listen here the terminate signal from 
    // mainThread to close the dependencies of this worker
    // Sth like the following will be awesome
    // thread.on('exit', () => { /* close dependencies */ })

    // Simulate a task which takes a larger time than MainThread wants to wait
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 10000);
    });
  })();
}
```

Comment: Terminate execute the function worker.emit('exit'). Then, you can listen it on  worker.on('exit', console.log);

Comment: @Amn yep, but I need to listen from the worker itself. `worker.on('exit', console.log)` is only available at parent process.

Answer (score 3):

You can signal exit to the worker thread via `worker.postMessage(value)` / `parentPort.on("message", (value) => {...})`, and then use `process.exit()` in the worker thread. Of course do the clean up first.

I would recommend to use an object as `value`, that way you will be able to pass multiple commands or date from main thread to worker thread.

```
const { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort } = require("worker_threads");

if (isMainThread) {
  const worker = new Worker(__filename);
  worker.on("message", console.log);
  worker.on("error", console.log);
  worker.on("exit", console.log);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Worker is gonna be terminated");
    // replace worker.terminate(); with something like
    worker.postMessage({ exit: true });
    // maybe add another setTimeout with worker.terminate() just in case?
  }, 5000);
} else {
  (async () => {
    // listen for message and do things according to passed value
    parentPort.on("message", (value) => {
      // worker threads do not have multiple listeners available for passing different event,
      // therefore add one onMessage listener, and pass an object with commands/data from main thread
      if (value.exit) {
        // clean up
        console.log("doing cleanup");
        process.exit(0);
      }
    });
    // add other logic for receiving messages from main thread

    console.log("I am the worker");
    // This thread will spawn its own dependencies, so I want to listen here the terminate signal from
    // mainThread to close the dependencies of this worker
    // Sth like the following will be awesome
    // thread.on('exit', () => { /* close dependencies */ })

    // Simulate a task which takes a larger time than MainThread wants to wait
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 10000);
    });
  })();
}
```